# Avada Theme - open Toggle with button or link

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, toggle

Is there a way to expand toggles via a button? Let say, I have a button that is positioned away from the Toggle section, and I want to use it to trigger the expanding and collapsing of the Toggle section, is this possible?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.